# How to delete a helpers file in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails, and after using `rails g controller Users` to generate a users controller, I decided to remove (i.e., `rm`) the generated helper in `app/helpers/users.rb`, because I realized I didn't need it. It seems ugly to keep a bunch of empty files around to me. This broke my app. When I try to visit any page in my, or run a test, I get this error: `Couldn't find UsersHelper, expected it to be defined in helpers/users_helper.rb`.

I fixed it by manually re-creating that file, but how do I get rid of it? Is that just not supported?

---

**Edits based on questions people asked**

The helper does not appear to be referenced explicitly anywhere, `grep -Ri UsersHelper .` only returns results for the module itself and a bootsnap cache file. The same command with `:helper 'user'` or 'helpers/users' returns nothing.

Comment: Did you use a scaffold? When I use the generator for models no helper is created.

Comment: Yeah, me too. I get a helper when I do `rails g controller...`

Comment: What version of rails is this?

Comment: Sorry, y'all are right, it's from a controller. I'll fix the question. @JamesMilani it's 5.2.0.

Comment: Does the word `UsersHelper` occur anywhere in your codebase? Or perhaps something like  `helper :users`?

Comment: @davidtbernal if that file contains anything and only in test shows broken, u can delete that required file in spec folder. Also, make sure probably yr included one of controller files.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev no results for `grep -Ri UsersHelper .` except for the module itself and a bootsnap cache (?). None for your other suggestion.

Comment: @7urkm3n not sure I follow. Spec folder? It's failing both in the app itself and in the tests.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev et. al. See the answer I added. I am using url helper functions that seem to require that module to exist. I'd love it if someone could explain in greater detail what's happening though, because those functions are not actually defined in the modules.

Comment: I've run into the same problem. Apparently, the ThingieController depends 'under water' on the existence of a ThingieHelper. I guess this comes from somewhere in [rails/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b13a5cb83ea00d6a3d71320fd276ca21049c2544/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb). An interesting find, this.

Comment: @davidtbernal Have you fixed this error ?

Answer (score 1):

If Rails is telling you that it can't find UsersHelper then it means that the module is called somewhere else in the project. When the page shows you the couldn't find message, it should also indicate the offending file where UsersHelper is being included (same with the test output). If you remove this reference, you should have no problem removing the module (or directory).

Comment: See my updated question, the module is not explicitly referenced anywhere. It seems to be implicitly referenced by url functions though (see my answer.)

Answer (score 1):

I sort of figured out the issue, but I still don't understand it.

I am using some url helper functions: `user_url(:id)` and `new_user_url`, and these apparently require the helpers to exist even though they are not explicitly defined there. If anyone can explain in more depth what's going on, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: `_url` does not call UsersHelper unless you have overwritten the native Rails url helper method with your own custom one. If you want to keep trying to debug, it would be helpful if you can edit the question with code samples and a stack trace.

Comment: Perhaps, you can distill this problem to a primitive rails app that we can clone from github or something. Because this problem (and its solution) indeed does not ring a bell at the moment.